# How to translate "Dothraki"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I added Dothraki to the list of languages we'll support in the FAQ of the [Amikumu Kickstarter](https://amikumu.com/ks) today, but it doesn't have an Esperanto form in the [Esperanto Wikipedia article about Dothraki](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dothraki_(lingvo)). How is *Dothraki* most often referred to in Esperanto when it's translated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name is pronounced as [ˈd̪o.θɾa.ki] in Dothraki according to the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet). The closest transliteration of that with Esperanto letters is *"dotraki"*, if you now add an *"-a"* you have a pretty close transliteration.

Example: *"La dotrakia lingvo estas lingvo parolata en fantasta verko."*

Comment: I think the name should be "la dotraka", without the i. This because the language is named after the Dothraki people, a member of which would be called a "dotrakio" going by your proposal. Whereas it would sound much more logical and Esperanto-like to have the set "dotrako, la dotraka, Dotrakio/Dotrakujo", mirroring "franco, la franca, Francio/Francujo" and countless similar terms.

Comment: Going by my proposal, Dotrakio would be another name for the Dothraki Sea (la Dotraka Maro), which I just read is a cultural and language region, not an actual country or other political union. But the same is true for the real-world examples such as Occitania (in Esperanto: Okcitanio/Okcitanujo), which disregards French provincial borders and only has political status as a language region.